# AngularJS- document.getElementById() - Why does element return null?

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, null

I have a checkbox on a dialog box that is opened when clicking a button in an AngularJS widget in my HTML form:

```
<form class="m-body" role="form" data-ng-submit="preview($event)" novalidate>
    ...
    <div data-ng-if="widget.name === 'display-box'" ng-dige="hideWidgetHeading()">
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="row">
            ...
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="row ui-checkbox-row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-i18n="Hide widget heading:"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
                <label class="ui-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="noWidgetHeading" ng-true-value= true ng-false-value= false ngChange="hideWidgetHeading()" ng-click="hideWidgetHeading()" >
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
```

In the `ctrl.js` file, I have the following function:

```
angular.module('app.widget').run(function($templateCache){
    ...
}).controller('WidgetPickerCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, fxTag, gPresets, appWidget){
    ...
    $scope.widget = undefined;
    ...
    $scope.checkboxModel = {
        value1 : true,
        value2 : false
    };
    ...
    var widgetHeadingCheckbox = document.getElementById("noWidgetHeading");
    console.log(widgetHeadingCheckbox);
    $scope.$watch('widgetHeadingCheckbox', function(){
        console.log("Value of checkbox has changed: ", widgetHeadingCheckbox);
    });

    function hideWidgetHeading(){
        if(widgetHeadingCheckbox){
            console.log("Value of widgetHeadingCheckbox in 'if': ", widgetHeadingCheckbox);
            return widgetHeadingCheckbox;
        } else {
            console.log("Value of widgetHeadingCheckbox in 'else: ", widgetHeadingCheckbox);
            return widgetHeadingCheckbox;
        }
    }
```

Currently, when I load the page, and click the button to open the dialog box, the checkbox is displayed on the dialog box unchecked. When I click it, it shows that it is checked, and if I click it again, it becomes unchecked again, as you would expect.

I am trying to use the `hideWidgetHeading()` JS function above to perform a different action when the dialog box 'Submit' button is pressed, depending on whether the checkbox is selected or not.

At the moment, if I select the checkbox (i.e. it's checked- its value should be `true`), and click the 'Submit' button on the form, I get the following output in my console:

> null
>
> Value of checkbox has changed: null
>
> Value of widgetHeadingCheckbox in else: null

I also get the same output in the console if I click the submit button when the checkbox is not checked...

Why is the value of my checkbox always `null`... I would expect it to be either `true` or `false`, but never `null`... Do I need to initialise it somewhere? I thought I had already done that in the HTML, when setting its `ng-true-value` & `ng-false-value`...

**Edit**

Following what dcrux has said in their answer, I have changed the HTML for the dialog box on which the checkbox is displayed to:

```
<div data-ng-if="widget.name === 'umw-tag-box'" ng-hide="hideWidgetHeading">
    ...
    <div class="row ui-checkbox-row">
        <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-i18n="Hide widget heading:"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-xs-6">
            <label class="ui-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ... ng-model="hideWidgetHeading">
                <span></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click the 'settings' button on the widget, the dialog box opens:

[image: configure item dialog]

However, when I then check the 'Hide widget heading' checkbox, what it actually hides is stuff from the dialog, rather than from the widget:

[image: Configure item hide]

What I want it to hide is the title bar of the widget itself, not anything from the dialog box:

[image: Configure item hide- intention]

How can I get it to hide something from the widget, rather than from the dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-model` in your input tag

```
<input type="checkbox" name="noWidgetHeading" ng-true-value= true ng-false-value= false ngChange="hideWidgetHeading()" ng-model="noWidgetHeading" ng-click="hideWidgetHeading()" />
```

Comment: That was what I had originally, but couldn't get it working, so removed the `ng-model`... I've just added it back, but I get the same output as I've mentioned in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

keep ng-model in your input tag `ng-model="noWidgetHeading"`

And also instead of reading from document

```
var widgetHeadingCheckbox = document.getElementById("noWidgetHeading");
    console.log(widgetHeadingCheckbox);
```

Try reading from scope

```
var widgetHeadingCheckbox = $scope.noWidgetHeading;
    console.log(widgetHeadingCheckbox)
```

It's just suggestion try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to change that ngChange to ng-change. Also, the clue is in the method name getElementById() - the id is missing, you have the name, but not the id.

Comment: I gave it an `id` with the same value as its `name`, but still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I would fist add `ng-model="noWidgetHeading"` back to the input.

Then change:

```
var widgetHeadingCheckbox = document.getElementById("noWidgetHeading");
 console.log(widgetHeadingCheckbox);

$scope.$watch('widgetHeadingCheckbox', function(){
    console.log("Value of checkbox has changed: ", widgetHeadingCheckbox);
});
```

to just:

```
$scope.$watch('noWidgetHeading', function(){
  console.log("Value of checkbox has changed: ", $scope.noWidgetHeading);
});
```

Next:

On you HTML- the input does not require `ng-true-value` or `ng-false-value` as using `'true'` and `'false'` is the default.  If you not want to use the default ensure you are using an expression so: `ng-true-value="'YES'"`

Ensure usage of directives is correct: `ngChange` should be `ng-change`.

`hideWidgetHeading()` is not exposed to the scope so can not be called from the front end. Consider binding it to $scope: `$scope.hideWidgetHeading = function(){...}`

See if these changes fix the problem.

Comment: The second thing you've said to change there is surely incorrect? I have got the HTML element `noWidgetHeading` and set it to the AngularJS variable `widgetHeadingCheckbox`- so surely `widgetHeadingCheckbox` is the variable that I want to pass into the `$watch()` function call?

Comment: I made the other changes you suggested, but most of my `console.log()` statements are still showing `null` or `undefined` values for the checkbox...

Comment: Because we have added the attribute`ng-model="noWidgetHeading"` to the input, watching the model is better than watching the element itself. Watching the $scope is a better way IMO, as the $scope.noWidgetHeading value is what will changing and what will be two way bound to the controller.

Comment: here is plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/pmdXIP0mh0MmP0afmWAP?p=preview  hit f12 to see it in action

Comment: Thanks for the example- this is almost exactly what I want... but I'm wondering if the reason that I can't get it working as you have in the example is because the element that I am trying to hide is not within the same scope as the checkbox...? The thing I want to hide is the 'heading' of a widget. The checkbox I'm trying to use to do it is currently displayed on a dialog box that pops up when you click a 'settings' button on that widget. I changed the `ng-model` I'm using to reflect what you have in your example, and while this has added the feature I want- it's added it to the wrong thing..

Comment: OP edited to show what's happening vs what I expect to happen.

Comment: As it is Prototypal Inheritance by setting `$scope.hideWidgetHeading` this does not consult parent scope(widget) instead creates a new property on the child scope(dialog), which is not available for use outside the widget and when the directive is hidden so is the isolate scope. To assign the property to the parent scope you need to been setting to an object.  So try declaring `$scope.viewModel = {}` on the controller . Then use `ng-model = "viewModel.noWidgetHeading"` in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a go, but it doesn't appear to do anything now when I check the checkbox & click the preview button...